# How to do CSV to JSON formatting with real-time database

Tags: json, flutter, csv, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a csv format which can be changed as well to achieve the task I am looking forward. I don't understand how can I format the csv to json I want to insert data in firebase real-time bulk amount of it but I am unable to achieve the formatting for it. I don't want 0,1,2,3... in database because  I have to match the users name and show the specific user data added from the csv to json.
[The format I want or I'm thinking will do the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv61s.png) Exporting this json creates this format

```
{
      "Database" : {
        "allemails" : {
          "a" : "data",
          "b" : "data",
          "c" : "data",
          "d" : "data",
          "email" : "xyx@gmail.com",
          "identity" : "sda",
          "name" : "nothing"
        }
      }
    }
```

When I convert the exported json to csv this gives me this format which is again not fine
[Json Exported from Firebase converted to csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gmM1.png)

[The CSV format I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HauGP.png)

Comment: I'm having a really hard time parsing your problem. Can you edit the question to show the code that you've already written to perform the conversion?

Comment: I don't have the code written yet I am stuck at making the logic out of it this is the best I can come up with to explain what is the issue. What I want is a csv with a lot of user's data to be inserted in the real-time database via json of course and that data I'll fetch later on in the app if the data gets imported successfully.

Comment: So: 1) parse the CSV, 2) convert it to JSON, 3) write the JSON to Firebase. Sounds doable, but writing the entire code is a bit beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. I recommend getting started with the first step, and reporting back if you get stuck there with a more concrete question. If you're having a hard time getting started even with the first step: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+parse+a+CSV+file+in+Flutter